# Before pseudo class unicode character appears different on mobile / iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, unicode

I have an issue with CSS pseudo class `:before`. The setup is pretty straight forward:

```
.homepage .slick-dots li button:before {
   font-size: 30px !important;
   content: "○" !important;
   color: #e41b13;
   opacity: 1;
}

.homepage .slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
   font-size: 30px !important;
   content: "●" !important;
   color: #e41b13;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

the unicode character is `U+25CB (9675) WHITE CIRCLE` and `U+25CF (9679) BLACK CIRCLE`. For whatever reason, it looks completely different in terms of scale on mobile:

[image]

Does anyone know why? Thanks

Comment: Not sure but you're overusing `!important` for sure. Any chance of demoing the problem?

Comment: @Paulie_D I am overwriting styles of another CSS, so the important is needed!

Answer (score 1):

Each font that provides a glyph for a particular character may look different in size and shape.

Presumably on the ‘mobile’ browser you are testing, the default font the browser is using doesn't provide a glyph for one of U+25CB or U+25CF, so the browser falls back to a less-preferred font to get a rendering for that character, and in that font the size of the circle is different.

In general the size of graphical characters will vary widely across platforms, both desktop and mobile as different people have different fonts installed. Worst case they may not have a glyph at all. If you need graphical fidelity, embed a custom font or use an image.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I thought about that, but assumed that both characters are not special so each browser is able to render them consistent. But if there is no guarantee for that, I will change it to images.